# Capruting time difference for the raw_input Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

say I am outputting something like `raw_input('What is your name?')` into the console. The message appears in the console and the user types in his name. I need to be able to capture the time difference between the time when the message was shown in the console and the time the user has hit Enter and inputted his name.

Comment: That's not making a lot of sense, could you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this?

```
from time import time
start=time() # time just before raw_input called
raw_input('What is your name?')
end= time() # time just after user give some input
print end -start
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is your problem. raw_input is blocking function, so you can simply read time before and after function and do something like:

```
import time
before = time.time()
value = raw_input()
after = time.time()
print "Waited for input for", after-before, "seconds"
```